# How is the iteratable id stored in #refernce variable within the div tag using angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a doubt for user.id is assign to reference variable. I tried and its not working. Can you please show one example of how its done? How is the iterable value stored in the reference variable.

Comment: How would someone even know what your user object consists of? Your question is poorly constructed and is lacking basic information to be answered.

Comment: Why do you have a `ng-template` there? Can you provide more code and explain why you have an `ng-template` there? Is this some template you are passing to some other component?

Comment: how to user.id is assign to (#id) .is possible or not possible.because i want to get the data.its value print.its cant store in id

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware what this template present?

They allow you to access either a DOM element or an instance of a component or directive in your current template. They are denoted by writing a hash sign (#) together with a name as an additional attribute of the DOM element. If this DOM element is just a plain one the variable contains a reference to it. In that case you can access any property of that DOM element through this variable.

Please refer the below example:

```
If you have a component living on the DOM element the variable will contain the instance of that component (and not the DOM element):

<my-component #variable [input]="'hello'"></my-component>
{{ variable.input }}

in your case:
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<ng-container #id *ngIf="user.method == update.business_type">{{ user.id }}
</ng-container>`
</div>
{{user.id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<ng-container [value]=user.id  #id *ngIf="user.method == update.business_type">{{ user.id }}
</ng-container>
</div>
```

there is a value attribute which store the data of `user id` & the reference variable store the data of the value.